# Term rewriting substitute with keeping old data structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have a problem where you have a tree data structure of some symbolic expression, and then I need to *expand* certain pieces of the tree using *rewrite rules* to obtain a final expanded data structure.

I can think of a few ways of doing this. First way, you simply replace the old node with the new expanded node. But the problem here is that you lose the ability to trace/debug back to the original data structure.

So then I think about a second approach, where I just traverse the old tree and construct a new tree, with the expanded nodes, *and* create a mapping between the two. This seems quite expensive to do, as you are essentially duplicating a potentially large structure and expanding it, keeping both in memory.

So that gets me wondering if there is a third way or other ways, where you can somehow create a mapping from the old to the new, while reusing as much as possible between the old and new data structures (while also creating the mapping like in #2). Is anything like this possible? How is it done?

Comment: So why no hibrid solution? Extend each node with a `previousVersion` pointer to the "original" node, and only use that property when you do a replacement. This means that the nodes that are not affected are still only stored once (with a null-pointer), while those that were impacted are actually new nodes with a back reference to their old versions.

Comment: Functional programmers think about this kind of thing a lot, usually in the context of functional data structures but sometimes for (e.g.) compilers that need greater visibility into structure sharing. Difficult to answer without more concrete details.